# How to copy and paste the value from one column to a new column

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy and paste the values in cell A1 and B1 into a new column next to cell A1 and B1.The code works for cell A1 and I get a copy of the value in cell B1 but I do not get the same result for cell B1 in cell C1.Please let me know what I am doing wrong because I am incrementing the range as the starting position and the end  position for the range changes a new column is added.

Range to copy

[image]

Result

[image]

```
Sub duplicate()

 Dim xlastcolo As Integer 
 Dim xcolo As Integer 

 xcolo = 1 
 xlastcolo = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

 Do Until xcolo = xlastcolo 
   If Cells(1, xcolo).Value <> "" Then
     ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Offset(0, 1).Insert
     Cells(1, xcolo).Copy
     Cells(1, xcolo).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial
     xcolo = xcolo + 2
     xlastcolo = xlastcolo + 1
   End If
Loop

xcolo = xcolo + 2

End Sub
```

Comment: So you want to copy the value from column A to column B but copy the previous value from column B to column C?

Comment: Instead of working with "copy-paste", I advise you to do the following: `Cells(1, xcolo).Offset(0, 1).Value = Cells(1, xcolo)`.

Comment: Don't think you need the loop. Get the count of columns you have used in current row, then using @Dominique suggestion, use `Offset` to copy all cells starting from **B1**. Don't have to worry about **A1**, it will already have the last value